# Magneto CMS Page Catalog View

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, block, magento-1.9

I am trying to show the same view as from a catalog view page in a CMS Page.

When I turn on path hints, it is loading file .../template/catalog/category/view.phtml

I have tried adding a block directive in the CMS page

```
 {{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="11"   template="catalog/product/specialoffer.phtml"}}
```

However, this lists the products, but the actual product blocks don't have the same appearance. There is a custom module that is getting loaded on the category view page, Atioc Swatch Images. However, it doesn't show on the CMS page.

I have tried to use the catalog view from the block directive, but I am not sure how to pass the category id value and it throws an error.

```
 {{block  type="catalog/category_view" category_id="11"   template="catalog/category/specialoffer.phtml"}}
```

and

```
{{block  type="catalog/category_view" id="11"   template="catalog/category/specialoffer.phtml"}}
```

The specialoffer.phtml is a copy of the list.phtml when I tried to use it in the product directory. 
And the specialoffer.phtml is a copy of the view.phtml when I tried to use it in the category directory.

Comment: On your first example where you load the block using catalog/product_list you say it doesn't have the same appearance, so is it just a styling issue or is there also functionality missing that would be loaded by the Atioc Swatch Images module? If it's just missing the style and JS from that module, you could add them in custom xml for your page

Comment: That worked thanks.